# jHipster, generated DTO does not contain related Child DTOs

Tags: jhipster

Use case: I would like to call a top level (parent) DTO that returns nested children DTO objects.

Example entities:

```
entity Person {
    firstName String
    lastName String
}

entity Dog {
    petName String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Person{dog} to Dog{person required}
}
```

The generated PersonDTO does not include the DogDTO.  I would like it to return the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "dogs": 
            [
                {
                    "id": 1                    
                    "petName": "Fido"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2
                    "petName": "Spot"
                }
            ]   
}
```

Thank you

Comment: will it be possible for you to change Person class to the following ? `entity Person {
    firstName String,
    lastName String,
    List<Dog> dogs
}`

Comment: Thanks for your response.   Your suggestions is already what the underlying Domain objects look like.   The jHipster entities and relationships that I listed will generate a Person Domain object that includes the List<Dogs> as you suggested.  My issue is that the jHipster generated DTO object not not include this nested/child Dog list.

Comment: You have to modify generated code manually

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Modifying generated code is not recommended. Check [jhipster custom and generated code good practices](https://www.slideshare.net/agoncal/custom-and-generated-code-side-by-side-with-jhipster)

Comment: @SebastianDuque I know this presentation very well and I like it BUT it all depends on your context. Maintaining a side-by-side approach with JHipster is not always easy and my opinion is that you should not put too much effort into it. I say that being on both sides: a JHipster user and a JHipster team member. My advice is just to focus on the business value of the solution you build rather than on the tools you use to build it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer about modifying the generated code.  That makes sense I think because my example was a OneToMany.  So, let me rephrase my question.  Even my ManyToOne and OneToOne relationships, which are supposed to Eager load, are not including sub objects in the DTO.  So, if none of my DTO ever includes any sub objects, then how can we take advantage of Eager loading?